# CakePHP and EasyPHP URL rewriting

Tags: apache, cakephp, localhost, easyphp

I'm tring to get CakePHP 2.2.3 working with EasyPHP 12.1 on my local machine. I'm getting an error from Cake that says:

> URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

1. Help me configure it please
2. I don't / can't use URL rewriting

I followed all of the instructions on the 'Help me configure it' page with no success. I've just installed both EasyPHP and Cake and have only modified the `http.conf` file.

I also created a virtualhost using EasyPHP's built in form.

Comment: To check if it is really enabled, create a file with just `phpinfo()` and look for `mod_rewrite`. Have you tried it?

Comment: I did try that and it is loaded.

Comment: What instructions you followed? Probably is missing or there is some error in your `.htacces` files. You need at least 3 files: on the root directory, in `app` and `webroot`. Additionally, you should check if the configuration variables `AllowOverride` is set to `All` on http.conf.

Comment: I followed the instructions located at [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess). What should be in my default .htaccess file? It currently contains the following:

Comment: Order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all

Comment: If this is your `.htaccess` in root directory, it wrong. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your `.htaccess` files are these. First, in your root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In `app` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And `webroot` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```